# Cloning of LinkedList with next and arbitrary pointer

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Why this code is giving false in return?
Question link- https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/clone-a-linked-list-with-next-and-random-pointer/1
and can you please tell me what is the space complexity of my code? as i have cloned it and returning that clone, so it will considered as O(n) or O(1)?

```
    Node copyList(Node head) {
            //Node temp=head;
            //res is the head pointer of cloned LL
            Node res=null;
            //rest is currently the head pointer of old LL
            Node rest=head;
            //r will going to be the head pointer of cloned LL
            Node r=null;
            while(rest!=null){
                if(res==null){
                    Node temp=new Node(rest.data);
                    res=temp;
                    r=res;
                }
                else{
                    Node temp=new Node(rest.data);
                    res.next=temp;
                    res=res.next;

                }
                //arb is arbitrary pointer
                 res.arb=rest;
                Node h=rest.next;
                rest.next=res;
                rest=h;

            }
            rest=r;
            while(rest!=null){
                if(rest.arb.arb!=null){
                    //System.out.println(rest.arb.arb.next.data);
                    rest.arb=rest.arb.arb.next;

                }

                rest=rest.next;
            }

        return r;        
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What is `arb`? What is `node` structure? And can u add comments to your code what you are trying to do? You are returning `r` how do you consider that as `false?

Comment: i will make the comments, arb is arbitrary pointer, but go through question as well, and copy and paste my code you will get it.

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to mutate the original list? If the testing code that executes your code would make a comparison between the original list and your returned clone, it would soon find they are not the same... because you mutated the original list. Oh, and yes, this will be considered O(n) time complexity. It is the best you can hope for.